# Formik is not maintaining order of keys for object passed into initialVals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, formik

I'm trying to re-order this object in order to sort some fields.  It works on tables that arent wrapped in a formik component.  Using formik it sorts the first time but then it seems to do some kind of caching and wont refresh the order anymore.  I cannot change the structure to an array.. It has to be an object.  The only other thing I thought of doing was adding some random value to the object but that wont pass code review.  Is there anything else I can do to get this object to sort when passed through formik?

```
  console.log('before', variationsByKey);
  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={variationsByKey}
      {({
        values,
      }) => {
        console.log('after', values);
```

Sorts a few times and then keeps memory of the object.  `before` is the correct sorting, and `after` ends up never changing.

`before {new_variation: {…}, on: {…}, off: {…}}`

`after {new_variation: {…}, off: {…}, on: {…}}`

code sandbox for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-brattain-29z53?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Formik reacts to `initialValues`. If, at any point after the form is rendered, you want to change your Initial Values object and have Formik repaint itself (which is allowed with `enableReinitialize`), you'd need to basically add a listener (`useEffect([..])` where you set the variable to a new object. I assume your initial values variable is `variationByKey`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setVariationsByKey(newObject);
}, [anyDependencyYouHave]);
```

If you need to sort or make any other changes, create a brand-new object and set it to your variable with the setter, `setVariationsByKey(newObject)`, in this effect, which watches whatever dependencies you have.

Comment: `variationsByKey` is actually a prop.  but even if i assign it to a brand new object using a spread before passing into initialVals its not updating inside formik.

Comment: I have the following, and all my re-initializations work. I define a state variable of my own, called `const [initialFormValues, setInitialFormValues] = useState({})` which is initially an empty object. Then, I call `setInitialFormValues` with whatever new objects need to be set, in various subsequent `useEffect` calls. Formik picks it up, based on `initialValues={initialFormValues}`. I would stay away from props. Just set a custom object, possibly based on a prop initially, but don't connect a prop to anything. Also verify that your latest object that you build is right.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue using that approach.  Pulling it from state isnt making a diff aside from causing a re-render.

Comment: If you want you can create a `codesandbox.io` with a Formik template and demonstrate your code there, would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: sure:   https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-brattain-29z53?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah, the `const ascData / descData` that you declare is somehow inaccessible to Formik after initialization. I verified that if you hard-code the object as in this example directly, it starts working: `const newData = order === 1 ? descData : {xyz: {key:'xyz',val:'uvw'}};` . Maybe some Formik experts can take a look at why that outer declaration isn't accessible. You might want to add your CodesandboxIO to the main post so it's more visible, or also post on the GitHub Issues forum.

Comment: That's not because it's inside the function. It's because in that example you're changing the structure of the object.  In my example I'm reordering identical objects and formik does some kind of caching if it doesn't see anything other than the order changing